# Where to put controller service and repository in deployment diagram

Tags: spring, architecture, uml, deployment-diagram

I want to put more in my deployment diagram like the controller layer, the service layer and the repository that are in my spring application. So where shall I put these 3 layers?

Here is my current deployment diagram: [image]

Do you think it can be a component inside  the `Application: java spring` artifact or is it wrong to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UML deployment diagram should reflect your architecture.  I'm not a spring / java expert,  but here some elements based on my understanding:

- I understand that the [Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) corresponds to the MVC controller, i.e. it processes input received by an application.  I also read, browsing across the net,  that the controller annotation can only be set on a class.  As a consequence,  I understand that the controller layer must be component of the `Application: Java Spring`.
- I understand that the [Spring repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) can be used inside a Spring container or as a standalone component. So it would seem possible to show it as a component in the `Application Java Spring`, but if it is used as standalone service on another server, it should be shown elsewhere, i.e. as a separate component inside TomCat, or as a component in another environment on another server.